# Can't open Typinator after upgrading to Catalina on Mac

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I upgraded to Catalina and can no longer open one of my apps (Typinator). I'm getting the error below.

I tried a few solutions I found online:

- right click while holding ctrl + click
- change accessibility settings to allow for Typinator

Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always worth it to visit the manufacturer's site

> ## Important Notification for Typinator users switching to Catalina.
>
> Typinator versions older than 8.2 do not work with Catalina and will refuse to launch. To ensure smooth transition to macOS Catalina, we therefore strongly recommend updating Typinator to version 8.2 **before** you install macOS Catalina on your computer.
>
> For more information, please see our [compatibility page](https://www.ergonis.com/products/tips/macos-compatibility.php)